# How to access a https secured web page using python

Tags: python, https

So basically the idea is to use python to login to a website and copy the content of a html page that can only be viewed after you have logged in. (under https)

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?
Requests? http.client.HTTPSConnection?

I currently have

```
h1 = http.client.HTTPSConnection(URL)  #question: what exactly should this url page be?
                                  https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginhl=en&continue=https://www.google.ca/
                                   or https://google.ca
userAndPass = b64encode(b"usrname:pwd").decode("ascii")
headers = { 'Authorization' : 'Basic %s' %  userAndPass }
#then connect
h1.request('GET', '$THEPAGETHATIWANTTOACCESS', headers=headers)
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've had much better success using [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) or [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) than httplib.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

```
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> r.headers['content-type']
'application/json; charset=utf8'
>>> r.encoding
'utf-8'
>>> r.text
u'{"type":"User"...'
>>> r.json()
{u'private_gists': 419, u'total_private_repos': 77, ...}
```